# OpenRefine sample extension not building

Tags: openrefine

I'd like to write my own [OpenRefine extension](https://docs.openrefine.org/technical-reference/writing-extensions)

Before starting any implementation, I just want to build [the sample extension](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/tree/master/extensions/sample) from OpenRefine just to get me started.

However, I'm getting the Maven error

```
 Could not resolve dependencies for project org.openrefine:sample:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT: org.openrefine:main:jar:3.0-SNAPSHOT was not found in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced ->
```

I simply cloned the OpenRefine repo and ran `mvn compile` from the `extensions/sample` folder.

any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I think the sample project has a wrong version in the pom.xml. it should be\

```
<version>3.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I fixed the issue in this PR https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/pull/4395